# Certain programs like Firefox and Slack don't respect display scaling on 22.04

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, wayland, 22.04

I've been using Ubuntu for a while now on my laptop, and I just installed the new LTS version 22.04.

I have a secondary display at the office. From the Gnome Settings I used to set the scaling to:

- 200% for the display of my laptop;
- 100% for the secondary display, which is a bit larger than my laptop's display.

This always worked very well with previous versions of Ubuntu, but now Ubuntu 22.04 shows Firefox as huge. Even the close/maximize/minimize buttons on the top-right of the window are ridiculously big.

The same problem happens to Slack and to Visual Studio Code, but not to Gnome Terminal and not to Gnome Settings. Default Gnome apps in general seem to show up at a normal size (both their content and the window close/maximize/minimize buttons).

Why?

---

### Update

I just realized that this only happens on Wayland sessions. Not on Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

You can try messing with the following settings ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#Fractional_scaling)):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1
```

And for firefox:

- run it with wayland support with `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/firefox#Wayland))
- in advanced preferences page (about:config), reset parameter layout.css.devPixelsPerPx to 1 if needed